# Maximum number of NSTimer that can be set in Single iPhone Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I am currently developing one application, in which my client wants to have some functionality in which i need to start lots of timer for different functionalities.

So, my question is that, by setting lots of NSTimer in single app, will it lead my App to crash?, or Is there any much side effect in application's performance?

Comment: How many timers are we talking about?

Comment: Have you tried with multiple times according to your requirement ? Did you fail or got any issue ?

Comment: I have tried upto 60 timers, until now i dont get any problem until now(checked in iphone 6 plus), but the no. of timers that will start from my app is dynamic, so i want to find the some maximum limit.

Comment: Then there is no limit specified in documentation. You can take how many you want but I wondered that it can be the requirement.

Comment: me too wondered, when i received such weird requirement from my client. Whatever, i think there might not be any limit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internally, NSTimers are all implemented on a single hardware timer. The OS keeps a central list of timers for all running apps and simply scheduels a single hardware timer for the soonest event.

Adding timers does not change the behaviour of your app. That said, in the same way that adding thready to an essentially single process machine makes runtime management easier, adding timers can help you partition your problem.

Number of timers isn't a problem.

Comment: @Rambo : I think you are right, but still not sure, i have tried upto 60 timers and tested it in iphone 6 plus, it is still working and no other effect on other part of app, so thinking you might be right

Answer (score 0):

NSTimers do consume battery depending on what is running in each timer loop and how many times it is running. Again, performance varies form device to device, as iPhone 6 has better RAM and memory then iPhone 5. So, might give memory warning and crash for certain devices.